# Using mongodb for form-building web application, schema considerations

Tags: mongodb, schema, database, nosql

I'm creating a web application with a dynamic survey creation & submission component. I'm using MongoDB to store the schema of the form and the form submissions.

I can imagine organizing this in several different ways:

1. Having all form submissions and form schemas as documents in a single collection.
2. Have separate collections for all form schemas and all form submissions
3. Have a separate collection for all form schemas, and create a new collection for all submissions of a form for each schema.

I'm still researching this and I come from the world of RDBMS, I'm a noob to NoSQL databases. Anyone have any advice?

---

**EDIT 1**
Forgot to address embedding the responses as a property within the form schema document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for two collections: **form** and **submissions**.

This is the approach scales horizontally well as you only have 2 collections to worry about.
I agree with @Gates VP about providing custom `_id` rather than the default `objectId` as you are spared the need for an extra index.

On the `submissions` collection if you set the `_id` format to `formID_userID` to get all the submissions all you'd need to do is:

```
db.submissions.find({'_id': '^formID'})
```

The bonus here is the anchored regex will use the `_id_` index - so its efficient.

---

For general reference and others stumbling upon this: there are some good presentations about schema design - that are worth checking out:

http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongodb-tokyo-2012/basic-application-and-schema-design
http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosv-2011/schema-design-principles-and-practice

Answer (score 2):

> Having all form submissions and form schemas as documents in a single collection.

You will want to avoid this one (#1). The simple reason here is that the form *submission* has a different role than the form *schema*. Mixing these in the same collection will make it more difficult to query.

> Have separate collections for all form schemas and all form submissions

To clarify, it sounds like you're suggesting two collections: `schema and`submission`.

This is a logical way to proceed. You will have one small `schema` collection and one large `submission` collection.

The key limitation will be the queries you make against that `submission` collection. Are you planning to query "across types"? Or are major queries centered about "submission type"?

If you end up including "submission type" on every query, then it makes sense to...

> Have a separate collection for all form schemas, and create a new collection for all submissions of a form for each schema.

The reason for this is simply the indexes. If you have one collection, you will need an index on "type". So by making separate collections, you can save an index. However, if you ever end up needing the sharding features, this can make for lots of collections to manage.

Of course, you can work around this "extra index", by being creative with the `_id`. MongoDB has an auto-generated `ObjectId` that it will use by default, kind of like an auto-increment ID. However, you can override this and create a smarter `_id`, something like `submissionid_userid`.

My preference is honestly for the last option. But really #2 & #3 are both good options, really just an issue of trade-offs in terms of code complexity and management complexity.